# Create a function/macro in R which can do more steps

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have 40 different data.frames with no systems in there names, like: nat69eqte, nahi_il and nahc_cpwtre. I want to create a function/macro in R which can proceed the following code in a easy way for all the data frames:

```
nat69eqte_wide <- spread(nat69eqte, key = time, value = values)
attr(nat69eqte_wide, "Symname") <- "nat69eqte"
lst_nat69eqte_wide <- wgdx.reshape(nat69eqte_wide, 2)
```

In each data.frame there are the columns time and values to be passed to spread.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any knowledge of your data, I can try to guess:
the following function assumes that in each data.frame there are the columns `time` and `values` to be passed to `spread`. If it is not the case you can add these columns as arguments of the function.

NB spread is now deprecated, instead, use `pivot_wider`

```
myfun <- function(df){
  name <- as_label(enquo(df))
  df_wide <- spread(df, key = time, value = values)
  attr(df_wide, "Symname") <- name
  lst_df_wide <- wgdx.reshape(df_wide, 2)
  return(lst_df_wide )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not allowed  to install new packages in my workspace so is it possible to change "name <- as_label(enquo(df))" to a different code which does not require to install packages

Comment: you can try with `name<-as.character(substitute(df))`. It is all base code